# Regular Expression starting and ending with special characters

Tags: regex, vba

I need to extract all matches from a huge text that start with `["` and end with `"]`. These special characters separate each record from database. I need to extract all records.

Inside this record there are letters, numbers and special characters like `-`, `.`, `&`, `()`, `/`, `{space}` or so.
I'm writing this in Office VBA.
**The pattern I have come so far looks like this: `.Pattern = "[[][""][a-z|A-Z|w|W]*"`.**
With this pattern, I am able to extract the first word from each record, with the starting characters `["`. The count of found matches is correct.
Example of one record:
`["blabla","blabla","blabla","\u00e1no","nie","\u00e1no","\u00e1no","\u00e1no","\u003Ca class=\u0022btn btn-default\u0022 href=\u0022\u0026#x2F;siea\u0026#x2F;suppliers\u0026#x2F;42\u0022\u003E\u003Ci class=\u0022fa fa-pencil\u0022\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E Upravi\u0165\u003C\/a\u003E \u003Ca class=\u0022btn btn-default\u0022 href=\u0022\u0026#x2F;siea\u0026#x2F;suppliers\u0026#x2F;form\u0026#x2F;42\u0022\u003E\u003Ci class=\u0022fa fa-file-pdf-o\u0022\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E Zmluva\u003C\/a\u003E \u003Ca class=\u0022btn btn-default\u0022 href=\u0022\u0026#x2F;siea\u0026#x2F;suppliers\u0026#x2F;crz-form\u0026#x2F;42\u0022\u003E\u003Ci class=\u0022fa fa-file-pdf-o\u0022\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E Zmluva CRZ\u003C\/a\u003E"]`

**The question is : How can I extract the all records starting with `["` and ending with `"]`?**
I don't necessary need the starting and ending characters, but I can clean that up later.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Remove the leading/trailing `["` and `"]` and split with `","`.

Comment: What separates a record? Is it either one of `,` or `;`?

Comment: `,` separates the records.

Comment: How about a non-greedy global match like this:
`.Pattern = "\[""[\s\S]*?""\]"`

Comment: I think I'll go the `split` way as @WiktorStribiżew suggested. Will to some cleanup at first and last record and I'm done.

Comment: @PetrSrníček your pattern is correct answer for my question. So now I have 2 methods to choose from. Thank you all.

Comment: @BranislavKollár: The `.Pattern = "\[""[\s\S]*?""\]"` will slow the macro performance with longer inputs. Always unroll lazy dot matching patterns like this if you want to keep performance at a good level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to get rid of the initial and trailing `["` and `"]` with either `Replace` or `Left`/`Right`/`Mid` functions, and then `Split` with `","` (in VBA, `""","""`).

E.g.

```
input = "YOUR_STRING"
input = Replace(Replace(input, """]", ""), "[""", "")
result = Split(input, """,""")
```

If you plan to use Regex, you can use `\["[\s\S]*?"]` pattern, but it is not that efficient with long inputs and may even freeze the macro if timeout issue occurs. You can unroll it as

```
\["[^"]*(?:"(?!])[^"]*)*"]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC6yR9/1). In VBA, `Pattern = "\[""[^""]*(?:""(?!])[^""]*)*""]"`

Note that with this unrolled pattern, you do not even need to use the workarounds for dot matching newline issue (negated character class `[^"]` matches any char but `"`, including a newline).

**Pattern details**:

- `\["` - `["` literally
- `[^"]*` - zero or more characters other than `"`
- `(?:"(?!])[^"]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `"(?!])` - `"` not followed with `]`
  - `[^"]*` -  zero or more characters other than `"`
- `"]` - literal character sequence `"]`